# How to change CharSet when using Indy TIdHTTPServer:ServeFile()?

Tags: c++builder, indy, httpserver, indy10

My Javascript, HMTL etc files are being served using `charset ISO-8859-1`, but I need then to have `charset=utf-8`. I've tried using `AResponseInfo->CharSet = "utf-8"` but it seems to make no difference.

I've done this, which works, but I'd rather not repeat the test for every possible file extension.

```
  AResponseInfo->ContentDisposition = "inline";
  if (paths::getExtension(requestedFile, true) == ".JS")
    AResponseInfo->ContentType = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8";

  AResponseInfo->SmartServeFile(AContext, ARequestInfo,uString(requestedFile));
```

(side note: This may be because I'm using a version of Indy10 that's a few years old with RadStudio 2010. What's the easiest way to upgrade Indy?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> side note: This may be because I'm using a version of Indy10 that's a few years old with RadStudio 2010.

That is more than "a few" years old, that is over a decade old.  RS2010 was released in 2009.  There have been many updates to `TIdHTTPServer` since that time, including several charset-related changes in 2010, 2012, and 2019.

> What's the easiest way to upgrade Indy?

The latest source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/

[Indy 10 Installation Instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925081341/http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx)
(note: link is from archive.org due to [current problems with indyproject.org](https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/))

Once you have upgraded to the latest Indy, `AResponseInfo->CharSet = "utf-8"` should work as expected.

`(Smart)ServeFile()` sets the `AResponseInfo->ContentType` property only if it is blank:

- If the new `ContentType` value specifies a `charset`, `AResponseInfo->CharSet` is set to that value.
- Otherwise, if the new `ContentType` value does not include a `charset`, AND `AResponseInfo->CharSet` is blank, AND the new `ContentType` value is a `text/...` media type, then `AResponseInfo->CharSet` is set to a default value, either `us-ascii` for XML types, otherwise `ISO-8859-1`.

Otherwise, `AResponseInfo->ContentType` and `AResponseInfo->CharSet` are left untouched, preserving whatever values they were holding before `(Smart)ServeFile()` was called.

When `AResponseInfo->WriteHeader()` is called, if `AResponseInfo->ContentType` is still blank, AND `AResponseInfo->ContentText` or `AResponseInfo->ContentStream` is assigned data, then `AResponseInfo->ContentType` is set to `text/html`, and `AResponseInfo->CharSet` is set to `utf-8` (RS2009+) or `ISO-8859-1` (pre-RS2009) if it is blank.

So, if you want to ensure a particular `charset` in the `Content-Type` header, you should be able to explicitly set `AResponseInfo->CharSet` to whatever you want, independently of what `AResponseInfo->ContentType` is set to, `TIdHTTPServer` will now preserve a pre-existing `CharSet` value whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks. My Indy version is (c) 2015 and supports Seattle, so I did upgrade many years ago! (Previously I've upgraded using the binaries from MJFreelancing but they haven't been updated for many years either.)